# How to create an array from the columns of a table in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML  table like this:

```
       SALES            RENTS    
    ROME   MILAN      ROME   MILAN    MONEY
```

The HTML code is the following:

```
<TR>
<TD CLASS=HD1 COLSPAN=2>SALES</TD>
<TD CLASS=HD1 COLSPAN=2>RENTS</TD>
<TD CLASS=HDCOLSEP>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>ROME</TD>
<TD>MILAN</TD>
<TD>ROME</TD>
<TD>MILAN</TD>
<TD>MONEY</TD>
</TR>
```

What I need, is to create with javascript an array like this:
    (ROME-SALES, MILAN-SALES, ROME-RENTS, MILAN-RENTS, MONEY).

I have already created the array that contains the element of the first row.
Below you can find my code as it was in the past (At the beginning I needed just to take the elements of the first TR). Now I need to modify it and to create an array as specified before.
I don't know if it is clear from the table, but the first ROME and MILAN columns are referred to the column SALES, the second ROME and MILAN are referred to the RENTS column, while MONEY doesn't have any dependence.
 Do you have any idea to do this?
Thanks in advance.

```
 function getColumnsVal(id) {
    var header = $("table#" + id + " thead tr:eq(1)");
    var header_fields = $("td", header);
    var header_vals = [];
    header_fields.each(function(idx, val) {
          var $$ = $(val);
          header_vals.push($$.text());
    });
     return header_vals;
  }
```

Comment: Hey, will the rows be consistent like this? And also, where is money here?

Comment: Hi, this is an example. In my table I have just more columns but the concept is the same. To be more clear, is like that SALES is a group name and below this group I have the columns ROME and MILAN; RENTS is another group name that contains the column ROME and MILAN, while money is the last colum and above money I have a blank cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely possible to read values from the table cells. I edited the post a bit to illustrate the code.

I presume that HTML structure is rigid and you always have two rows of titles in the `thead` and somewhat random number of merged cells in the first row.

You’d want to match the number of columns in both rows, i.e. take the colspan number into account when traversing the cells.

Read both rows and generate strings by combining cell values in corresponding columns.
For example:

```
function readTableRow(row) {
    var values  = [];
    $("td", row).each(function(index, field) {
        var span = $(field).attr("colspan");
        var val = $(field).text();
        if (span && span > 1) {
            for (var i = 0; i<span; i++ ) {
                values.push(val);
            }
        } else {
            values.push(val);
        }
    });
    return values;
}

function getColumnsVal(id) {
    // Read the first row, taking colspans into account
    var first_row = $("table#" + id + " thead tr:eq(0)");
    var first_row_vals = readTableRow(first_row);

    // Read the second row, taking colspans into account
    var second_row = $("table#" + id + " thead tr:eq(1)");
    var second_row_vals = readTableRow(second_row);

    if (first_row_vals.length != second_row_vals.length) {
        return null;
    }

    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i<first_row_vals.length; i++) {
        results.push([first_row_vals[i].trim(), second_row_vals[i].trim()].filter(function (el) {return el}).join("-"));
    }

    return results;
}

function displayResults(results) {
    var result = "RESULT: <br />";
    results.forEach(function(r) {
        result = result + r + "<br />";
    });
    $("#result").html(result);
}

displayResults(getColumnsVal("sample"));
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/adanchenkov/n61dqfrs/